# Comparing multiple objects with a method to find the largest value?

Tags: java, class, object, methods, compare

Hey I'm trying to figure out a method in my main code to compare the age attribute of the class DVD with all other instances of the object to see which attribute is the largest and smallest. Can any one steer me in the right direction. I can post the main method and other class if that helps?

DVD Class:

```
public class DVD
{
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String genre;
    private int age;

    public DVD(String id, String title, String genre, int age)
    {

        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getId()
    {

        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public String getGenre()
    {
        return genre;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    //Setters

    public void setID(String idIn)
    {
        id = idIn;
    }

    public void setTitle(String titleIn)
    {
        title = titleIn;
    }

    public void setGenre(String genreIn)
    {

        genre = genreIn;
    }

    public void setAge(int ageIn)
    {
        age = ageIn;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        //Building string here
        String x = "The id is: "+id+
            "\nThe title is: "+title+
            "\nThe genre is: "+genre+
            "\nThe age is: "+age;
        return x;

    }
}//end of class
```

DVDShop Class:

```
public class DVDShop
{
    //attributes (instance variables)
    private DVD[] dvdList;
    private int total;

    //Constructors
    public DVDShop (int maxNum)
    {
        dvdList = new DVD[maxNum];
        total=0;
    }

    //accessor 
    public int getTotal()
    {
        return total;
    }

    // check if the list is full
    public boolean isFull()
    {
       if (total == dvdList.length)
       {
          return true; // list is full
       }
       else
       {
          return false; // list is empty
       }
    }

    // check if the list is empty
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
       if (total == 0)
       {
          return true; // list is empty
       }
       else
       {
          return false; // list is not empty
       }
    }

      // add an item to the array
  public boolean add(DVD DVDIn)
  {
    if (!isFull()) // check if list is full
    {
      dvdList[total] = DVDIn; // add item
      total++; // increment total
      return true; // indicate success
    }
    else
    {
      return false; // indicate failure
    }
  }



     // helper method to find the id of a specified account
      public int search(String dvdNumIn)
      {
        for(int i = 0; i < total; i++)
        {
          DVD tempDVD = dvdList[i]; // find the account at index i
          String tempNumber = tempDVD.getId(); // get dvd number
          if(tempNumber.equals(dvdNumIn))
          {
            return i;
          }
        }
         return -999;
      }


  public boolean delete(String numberIn)
  {
     int index;

     index = search(numberIn); // call the search method first 
                               // if it could find the DVD it will return the element in the array that it is stored
                               // if  not it will return a dummy value of -999
     if(index == -999) 
     {
         return false; // remove was unsuccessful
     }
     else
     {   
         for(int i = index; i<= total-2; i++)
         {
             dvdList[i] = dvdList[i+1];
         }
         total--; // decrement total number of DVDs
         return true; // remove was successful
     }
  }


   public DVD getItem(String numIn)
  {
    int index;
    index = search(numIn);

    if(index == -999)
    {
      return null; // indicate invalid index
    }
    else
    {
      return dvdList[index];
    }
  }
}
```

Main Method:

```
    public class Question1
    {
        public static void main (String args[])
        {
            //creation of instance of DVDs called myDVDshop size 10
            DVDShop myDVDshop = new DVDShop(10);

            int choice;
            int i;

            //start of do while() loop for repetition
            do{
                System.out.println();

                System.out.println("Shop System");

                System.out.println("1. Add DVD");
                System.out.println("2. Search for DVD");
                System.out.println("3. Show number of DVDs in shop");
                System.out.println("4. Delete a DVD");
                System.out.println("5. Show Details of a DVD");
                System.out.println("6. Exit System");
                System.out.print("Please enter your choice: ");
                choice = EasyScanner.nextInt();

                System.out.println();

                //Start of switch()

                switch(choice)
                {

                    case 1:
                    addDVD(myDVDshop);
                    break;  


                    case 2:
                    searchDVD(myDVDshop);
                    break;

                    case 3:
                    Stock(myDVDshop);
                    break;

                    case 4:
                    deleteDVD(myDVDshop);
                    break;

                    case 5:
                    showDetails(myDVDshop); 
                    break;

                    case 6:
                    System.out.println("Goodbye..."); 
                    break;
                    default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid entry, please reenter valid selection");

                }//end of switch()

           }while(choice!=6);


       }//end of class
       //start of methods



   private static void showDetails(DVDShop myDVDshop)
  {
        String number;

        // get details from user

        System.out.print("Enter Id of DVD: ");
        number = EasyScanner.nextString();

        DVD theDVD = myDVDshop.getItem(number);
        if (theDVD == null)
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("No such DVD exists");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("DVD Id: " + theDVD.getId());
            System.out.println("DVD title: " + theDVD.getTitle());
            System.out.println("DVD genre: " + theDVD.getGenre());
            System.out.println("DVD age category: " + theDVD.getAge());
            System.out.println();
        }
  }



       private static void  deleteDVD(DVDShop myDVDshop)
       {
            String id;
            boolean toDelete;

            System.out.print("Please enter the id number of the DVD you would like to delete: ");
            id = EasyScanner.nextString();

            System.out.println();

           toDelete = myDVDshop.delete(id);

                    if (toDelete == true)           
                    {
                      System.out.println("The DVD has been deleted from the system");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      System.out.println("The DVD could not be deleted from the system");
                    }

           System.out.println();
       }


       private static void addDVD(DVDShop myDVDshop)
           { 
               String id, title, genre;
               int age;
               boolean ok;
              // DVDs myDVDshop = new DVDs(10);
               // Entering required data
              System.out.print("Enter id number: ");
              id = EasyScanner.nextString();

              System.out.print("Enter title of DVD: ");
              title = EasyScanner.nextString();

              System.out.print("Enter genre of DVD: ");
              genre = EasyScanner.nextString();

              System.out.print("Enter age category of DVD: ");
              age = EasyScanner.nextInt();

              System.out.println();

              DVD DVD1 = new DVD(id,title,genre,age);

              ok = myDVDshop.add(DVD1);

                    if (ok == false)           
                    {
                      System.out.println("The list is full");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      System.out.println("DVD added");
                    }

             System.out.println();
    }

        private static void searchDVD(DVDShop myDVDshop)
        {

           //Requesting value from the user to search for.

           System.out.print("Which DVD id do you want to search for: ");
           String idIn=EasyScanner.nextString();

           System.out.println();

           int search1 = myDVDshop.search(idIn);

                 if(search1 == -999)
                 { 
                     System.out.println("DVD not in the system");
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     System.out.println("The DVD is in the system at position number "+search1+ " in the array.");

                 }

           System.out.println();         
        }

        private static void Stock(DVDShop myDVDshop)
        { 
          System.out.println("Total stock is: "+myDVDshop.getTotal());
        }

}//end of class
```

Comment: Do you want to sort a collection of DVD objects by age?

Comment: Post what you tried. Tell us the expected output given a defined input. Your description of the problem is not very clear: "compare the age attribute of the class DVD with all other instances of the object" doesn't mean much.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I want to search all the objects and find the largest age and smallest age.

Comment: Added, basically I'm wondering what the code would be to compare the ten dvds and print the minimum and miximum

Comment: @user2988501: you've posted a lot of irrelevant code, and nothing to show what you tried to get the mninmum and maximum age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the `Comparable<T>` interface on the `DVD` class like so:

```
public class DVD implements Comparable<DVD>
```

This requires you to define a new method; `compareTo`

This allows you to define how two objects should be ordered with respect to each other. In this instance, it would make sense for an older DVD to be "greater" than a newer DVD, so your (very basic) implementation of `compareTo` could look something like this:

```
public int compareTo(DVD that) {
    if (age > that.getAge()) {
        // this is older than that
        return 1;
    } else if (age < that.getAge()) {
        // this is newer than that
        return -1;
    }

    // this is the same age as that
    return 0;
}
```

Once you have done that, you can use `Arrays.sort(dvdList)` to get your collection sorted into age order. From there, it is a matter of picking the first and last elements in the collection, which will be your oldest and newest `DVD`s respectively.

In practice you might want to add some null-checking to compareTo to avoid problems if `that` is `null`.

Comment: Why not use Collections.min() and Collections.max()? Sorting the list just to get the min and the max is a waste of time.

Comment: @JBNizet The OP is declaring dvdList as an array, not a Collection, so Collections.min() and Collections.max() don't apply here unless you also change the declaration of dvdList.

Comment: then he should use `Collections.min(Arrays.asList(dvdList))`, or use a List from the beginning.

Comment: Using a `List` from the start would be preferable yes, but isn't strictly necessary to accomplish the objective. I disagree that they should call `Collections.min(Arrays.asList(dvdList))` or the max equivalent however, as this involves creating a new `ArrayList` instance, copying each element from the array into it, and then iterating over the new list to find the min/max element each time. The direct index access that sorting allows is much faster, especially if you're doing it frequently.

Comment: Arrays.asList() doesn't create a java.util.ArrayList instance, and doesn't make any copy. It just returns a thin wrapper over the original array. Read the source code and the javadoc. It's basically as fast as doing `new Integer(i)`.

Comment: From the source of Arrays.java: `return new ArrayList<>(a);`. Might not be copying the elements, granted, but it's still a new instance, and is still iterating the collection each time.

Comment: Now click on that ArrayList, and see where it leads you. That ArrayList is an inner class of Collections. Not java.util.ArrayList. Its constructor does `a = Objects.requireNonNull(array);`. It doesn't copy anything, and it doesn't iterate at all. It just keeps a reference to the original array. Collections.max(Arrays.asList(array)) is O(n). Arrays.sort() is O(n * log(n)).

Answer (score 0):

`Can any one steer me in the right direction.`

Add method of finding largest and smallest thing to DVDShop class like following.

```
public class DVDShop
{
    private DVD[] dvdList;
    ---snip---
    public int largestAge()
    {
        //find and return largest age from dvdList.
    }

    public int smallestAge()
    {
        //find and return smallest age from dvdList.
    }
}
```